# Loading multiple high quality bitmaps and scaling them

Tags: android, bitmap

I've got a serious performance issue in my app, when loading up bitmaps it seems to take up way to much memory.

I have a drawable folder which contains the bitmap sizes for all android devices, these bitmaps are of high quality. Basically it goes though each bitmap and makes a new one for the device depending on the size. (Decided to do it this way because it supports the correct orientation and any device). It works but it's taking up way to much memory and takes along time to load. Can anyone make any suggestions on the following code.

```
public Bitmap getBitmapSized(String name, int percentage, int screen_dimention, int frames, int rows, Object params)
{
    if(name != "null")
    {
        _tempInt = _context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", _context.getPackageName());
        _tempBitmap = (BitmapFactory.decodeResource(_context.getResources(), _tempInt, _BM_options_temp));
    }
    else
    {
        _tempBitmap = (Bitmap) params;
    }

    _bmWidth = _tempBitmap.getWidth() / frames;
    _bmHeight = _tempBitmap.getHeight() / rows;

    _newWidth = (screen_dimention / 100.0f) * percentage;
    _newHeight = (_newWidth / _bmWidth) * _bmHeight;

    //Round up to closet factor of total frames (Stops juddering within animation)
    _newWidth = _newWidth * frames;

    //Output the created item
    /*
    Log.w(name, "Item");
    Log.w(Integer.toString((int)_newWidth), "new width");
    Log.w(Integer.toString((int)_newHeight), "new height");
    */

    //Create new item and recycle bitmap
    Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(_tempBitmap, (int)_newWidth, (int)_newHeight, false);


    _tempBitmap.recycle();

    return newBitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an excellent guide over on the Android Training site:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

It's about efficient loading of bitmap images - highly recommended!

Comment: I've read this and it seems to be the only way to load bitmaps in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This will save space.  If not using Alpha colors it would be better not to use one with the A channel.

```
        Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inScaled = false;
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    // or   Bitmap.Config.RGB_565 ;
    // or   Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444 ;

        Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(_tempBitmap, (int)_newWidth, (int)_newHeight, options);
```

Comment: `_8888` (4byte per pixel incl alpha) is the largest one you can get memory-wise. The bad thing about using other configs is that drawing images might get slower if you use e.g. 565 since the gfx hardware is usually optimize for 32bit colors

Comment: I was just offering an example, but the end compression would depend on the use.  I use various configurations.  I don't use alpha on my scrolling backgrounds because there is nothing behind them and compress things such as explosions more since they usually run the animation quickly.  I greatly improved when I switched, but I do believe it depends on the use.